# Make Separated APK which linked from one APK

Tags: android, hyperlink, apk

I want to make one main APK which has menu inside it that linked to other APK so that I can update each sub-APK independently. And I also want so that when each menu clicked first it will check whether the sub-APK we have is already updated to the latest version or not (note that this is only for private use application). Thanks before :)

Comment: Show us your attempt at the code.

Comment: This sounds overly complicated. By private use, do you mean to say, it won't be updated through google play.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you want

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect

The app used to be open source. I'm not sure what happened to the link to their repository. Now it seems they turned it into a commercial product. 
http://www.inappsquared.com/devappsdirect.html